# Is there a way to not buffer data from an UDP socket

Tags: python, sockets, synchronization, udp, timing

I am making a server sending clock ticks as a multicast message using UDP. The code for the server is this:

```
import socket
import struct
import sys
import time

multicast_group = ('224.3.29.71', 10000)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.settimeout(0.2)
ttl = struct.pack('B', 255)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl)

try:
    i = 0
    while True:
        #print "tick"

        sent = sock.sendto(str(i), multicast_group)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1.0/25.0)

finally:
    print "closing socket"
    sock.close()
```

I want the client to do something when it receives a tick but skip the ticks it missed while doing its processing.

For example, if the client receives tick #1 and it misses tick #2 and tick #3 while doing the processing, I want tick #4 to be the next received message.

However, it seems that since the socket is buffered, it sometimes receives the ticks it should skip.

Here is the code for the client:

```
import socket
import struct
import sys
import time

multicast_group = '224.3.29.71'
server_address = ('', 10000)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.setblocking(0)

group = socket.inet_aton(multicast_group)
mreq = struct.pack('4sL', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

while True:
    try:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print data
        time.sleep(1) #simulate processing
    except socket.error:
        pass
```

Output on the client:
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
...

What should I be doing to get the behavior I want?

EDIT: To expand on the problem, I record an event every time the client receives a tick. I want to record the following sequence: [trigger, pause, trigger, pause] but instead, since some ticks were buffered, I get: [trigger, pause, trigger, trigger, trigger], making my events to close to each other in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The socket buffer is inside the kernel, and not inside python. Whenever a packets comes in, it is put into this buffer until the user space reads it from the kernel. You can use setsockopt to change the size of the buffer, but this is a size in bytes and not in packets. And it is not a good idea to make it to small, because if a packet is received on the machine and the socket buffer is already full, the new packet will just discarded.

A better way would be to leave the socket buffer like it is, but set the socket to non-blocking and then call recvfrom until you get no more data - then process the last packet you've read.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried modifying my code to read all the buffer but I still run in the same problem. Because some past ticks are in the buffer, they are processed instead of being dropped. I think I can rephrase my question as this:

I want a blocking recv that drops packets received between the last recv() call and the current one. Is setting the packet size with setsockopt as you mentionned before the only way?

Comment: Decreasing the buffer size does not solve your problem, because it will discard incoming packets if the buffer gets full. My proposal was not that you read and process all packets until no more are available, but you receive all, but only process the last. If even this was too far away, than the kernel buffer was too small and discarded incoming packets, so you either have to increase the buffer or just try to process packets more often. There is no way to discard the old packets inside the kernel if new arrive. Or maybe you should try to rethink the way your application works at all.